# Add SKScene overlay in RealityKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

In ARKit, we can easily add an SKScene overlay as a HUD (head up display).

```
let hud = SKScene(size: sceneView.frame.size)

sceneView.overlaySKScene = hud
```

How do you do this in RealityKit? As there are no overlaySKScene in ARView?

Answer (score 2):

You can create this overlay programmatically:

```
import SpriteKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    let skView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 150))
    let scene = SKScene()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arView.backgroundColor = .black
        skView.showsFPS = true
        scene.backgroundColor = .systemTeal

        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
        boxAnchor.steelBox?.scale = [9,9,9]
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)

        arView.addSubview(skView)
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

[image]